# Changing File Encoding in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, file-encodings

I just installed Visual Studio 2015 Professional (Version 14.0.23107.0 D14REL).

I created a simple MFC project and when I tried to change file encoding, Visual Studio just shows a few encoding types.

- Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001
- Unicode - Codepage 1200
- Unicode (Big-Endian) - Codepage 1201

My favorite encoding is UTF-8 without BOM (65001) but this is not in the list.

How can I fix this???

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem after upgrading to windows 10.
Installing the US English language pack restored the full list of encodings on VS.
Just installs it without making it the default language.